# How to use trigger in VoltDB

Tags: trigger, voltdb

As I know, trigger isn't supported in VoltDB. If anyone has updated news about trigger on VoltDB for nowadays, would you please let me know.

So my question: is it possible to implement a trigger-style action in VoltDB?

What I need is like following:

Once I commit an operation in VoltDB, like inserting a tuple, updating a tuple or deleting a tuple, a C function or executable binary could be executed, and the old/updated tuple value could be passed to the function.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

VoltDB has very limited support for triggers in DDL, the way some traditional SQL databases do. You can tell it to run a SQL statement when a table reaches a certain row count, which is often used to truncate older data.

Within stored procedures, there is tremendous support for very flexible logic. You can perform arbitrary database operations when certain conditions are met.

VoltDB does not have an official way to call a C function or executable with data. Perhaps you could expand on what you're trying to accomplish? If this is part of a change-data-capture scenario, you might want to take a look at VoltDB's Export technology, which is a push-based system for moving data to a downstream system in a reliable way.

https://voltdb.com/products/fast-data-ingest-and-export
https://docs.voltdb.com/UsingVoltDB/ChapExport.php

Comment: I have zero experience with VoltDB but it seems you can run Java from stored procedures: https://docs.voltdb.com/UsingVoltDB/ddlref_createprocjava.php